# <Super>Space half blocked in Gnome

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I am unable to use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keystroke to launch ULauncher in Gnome 3.38.5 on Debian 11. The odd part is if I use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>any other key</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
it works, and continues to work as long as I hold <kbd>Super</kbd>. It seems <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>any other key</kbd> escapes some input method and allows the pass through to Gnome? It's very strange. All my other keybinds work as expected, including those using <kbd>Super</kbd>. I don't believe it's a hardware issue or anything.

For example: Highlighting a character in the URL bar of Firefox, press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> will change the field somewhat and highlight the outer box, not releasing  and pressing space again launches uLauncher as expected.

In a gnome-terminal - Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> inputs a "d" character then still holding <kbd>Super</kbd> hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> opens the launcher. Same with any other key <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (holding super the whole time) inputs a space then opens the launcher.

Steps taken:

- Remove <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> from current Gnome keybinds (keyboard language switching)
- Ensure it's not set in `ibus-setup`

Any idea how I can make it not require that <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>any other key</kbd> sequence before opening the launcher?

Comment: Shout out @Evangard for those changes to buttons in markdown. Very cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to "mutter" being bound to <kbd>Super</kbd>, it can be fixed with:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/overlay-key "'Alt_R'"
```

(which sets it to Right Alt key instead), or set it to `''` to remove it all together.

via: https://askubuntu.com/a/850202

Go give them an upvote if that helped.